# How to download an image on Android wear?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have an ArrayList of Serialization objects on my handheld.

I found a solution to send it to my wearable device.

[Can I send custom objects to Android Wear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938273/can-i-send-custom-objects-to-android-wear)

In my Object I have the URL of an image and in my handheld I am using Picasso to download the image from the URL (es in a ImageView).

Can I download the image in the wearable? (I think no).

Should I download all the images of the ArrayList in the handheld and send it putting them as assets in a DataMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download images directly from the Wear as there's no direct internet access.

However you're on the right path by downloading images on mobile (e.g. using Picasso), then transferring them to the Wear via an `Asset`.

There's a tutorial with all the code required on how to send an image using an `Asset` in the Android training section:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

Comment: This answer is really old. I m actually working on Android Wear using Glide downloading images from Firebase Storage into ImageViews  and it works fine but its too slow. Did someone knows a faster library?(I couldn't make DaVinci works cause its also out of date(3 years old to be exact))